# Sellenium, cant find button like in Instagramm

Tags: python, selenium, bots, instagram

hi
The problem is that selenium cannot find the button click like, as soon as it does not work through xpath, always gives different errors. [First error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQxHX.png)

In general, the bot enters Instagram by posts (according to the global hashtag), but cannot like. Need to find this button

Comment: put code and error as text instead of image

Answer (score 0):

Your code raises the error `list object has no attribute click` because the command `like = browser.find_elements(...)` returns a list of elements, so if you want to click one element you have to specify its index in the list, for example `like[0].click()` instead of `like.click()`.

By looking at the HTML we see that the like button has a `svg` descendant with attribute `aria-label='Like'`, so we can first target the `svg` with `//*[local-name()='svg'][@aria-label='Like']` and then go back to the `button` parent with `/parent::div/parent::button`.

By using `WebDriverWait` and `EC` (expected conditions) we can be sure that the button is visible and clickable on the page.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

xpath_like_button = "//*[local-name()='svg'][@aria-label='Like']/parent::div/parent::button"
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath_like_button))).click()
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Макс\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 78, in <module>
    search_by_hashtag("lamborghini")
  File "C:\Users\Макс\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 66, in search_by_hashtag
    WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath_like_button))).click()
  File "C:\Users\Макс\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 95, in until

Comment: again error, idk

Comment: @user477346 please post full code and full error in the question, as text not as image

Comment: @user477346 Don't put the code here in comments but in the question

Comment: @user477346 Edit the question and paste full code and errors there

Comment: https://dropmefiles.com/sp79c

Sry I cant edit question , i added to dropmefiles file with code

Comment: @user477346 ok, for security reasons i'd like not to download any file, instead paste the code here and then send me link https://pastebin.com/

Comment: https://pastebin.com/UG2U2mTC

Comment: @user477346 also paste the error in another pastebin and send link

Comment: https://pastebin.com/8ug9dQks

Comment: @user477346 Ok, I think it is a problem with the language of the site. In which language is instagram displayed on your computer?

Comment: @user477346 On my computer is english, so I can search the like button using `//*[local-name()='svg'][@aria-label='Like']`, but if your language is different then you have to change `'Like'` to something else

Comment: @user477346 To check how the button is called, open the DevTools (right click > Inspect) and select the like button so that it shows the HTML. You should see something like `<svg aria-label="Like" class="_ab6-" color="#fafafa" fill="#fafafa" height="24" role="img" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24">`

Comment: first time that work but when i change my username and password something went wrong error: https://pastebin.com/1QnVqmjG

Comment: @user477346 `TimeoutException` means that the driver was not able to find the button in 10 seconds (you can increase seconds by replacing 10 with something else here `WebDriverWait(browser, 10)`)

Comment: same problem (made 100)

Comment: @user477346 What about the `svg` that I asked you before?